# error: incompatible types: Intent cannot be converted to Intent[]

Tags: android, android-intent

i was creating a persistent notification channel for my android app, since google announced that you cant be run your android app on the above version than oreo, so i installed all the latest sdk android api kit and now along with that i also need to create a persistant notification

but when i m creating a notification, and run this code, im getting this error, actually i want to show th full error

error: incompatible types: Intent cannot be converted to Intent[]
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivities(this,0, intent1, 0);

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TcGOu.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use PendingIntent.getActivity not PendingIntent.getActivities

Comment: thank you so much bro this really solve my issue thank you so much

Comment: glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

if your android versson is flagmingo so cooding

Intent myintent= new Intent(MainActivity.this,MainActivity2.class);
startActivities(new Intent[]{myintent});

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34656976)